# Proof of Binomial Coefficients Comparison Inequality

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, proof-writing, binomial-coefficients

Please help to prove the inequality

$$ \binom{a}{b}\leq\binom{a+j}{b+i}$$
For 
$i\leq j$

Using the basic identity $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ I have proceeded to

$$
1 \leq \frac{(a+j)\cdots(a+1)}{((b+i)\cdots(b+1)) \cdot ((a-b+j-i)\cdots(a-b+1)) }
 $$ 
Here I am stuck...

Comment: You probably need some more conditions on $a$, $b$, $i$, and $j$. If $b=0$, and $i=0$, then the two binomial coefficients are equal.

Comment: First do the case $i=j.$

Comment: @Justpassingby That is trivial. Problem start after  $(a-b+j-i)\cdots(a-b+1)$ comes in denominator.

Comment: @Galaxy if that is given then the rest is not so complicated, either. Would you call the case $i=0$ trivial as well?

Comment: I think so. More interested for case $i,j \in \mathbf{N}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let $i = j$.

$$\binom {a}{b} \leq \binom {a+i}{b+i}$$

$$\frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!} \leq \frac{(a+i)!}{(b+i)!(a-b)!} $$

$$\frac{a!}{b!} \leq \frac{(a+i)!}{(b+i)!} $$

This holds true.

Now, since $i \leq j$ it is sufficient to prove

$$\binom {a+i}{b+i} \leq \binom {a+i+1}{b+i}$$

$$\frac{(a+i)!}{(b+i)!(a-b)!}  \leq \frac{(a+i+1)!}{(b+i)!(a-b +1)!} $$

$$\frac{(a+i)!}{(b+i)!(a-b)!}  \leq \frac{(a+i+1)(a+i)!}{(b+i)!(a-b+1)(a-b)!} $$

$$1  \leq \frac{(a+i+1)}{(a-b+1)} $$

$$a-b+1 \leq a+i+1 $$

$$-b \leq i $$

which also holds true since $b, i \geq 0$ by definition.

We can now conclude

$$\binom {a}{b} \leq \binom {a+i}{b+i}  \leq \binom {a+i+1}{b+i} \leq \dots \leq \binom {a+i+n}{b+i}$$

for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$